Should I conduct a multilevel for this or another analysis? Need help
I have three sources of data (teachers, parents and students) assessing students, in three waves. I want to assess all and see the differences between moments but then I also want to use variables for each source to identify possible explanatory and differences (e.g., for parents use academic level and work, for students gender and age, for teachers the identified risk level of each student).
I was thinking about doing a repeated measures analysis and then multiple regression. This per source. However I am now thinking that I could possible do a multilevel but I am not sure, since I am no expert in this matter.
Can you help me with this? What do you suggest?
Probably I am not giving you enough information, but let me know if I can clear it out.
Thank you so much!

Welcome to the site. I think you meant to provide a link but it is missing.

Also, just to be clear, the assessments were of the students, yes? So you have student self-assessments, teacher assessments, and parent assessments. Did they use the same tool? Are the ratings/scores all on the same scale? An example will help.

No link. Yes, the assessment from all sources are related to students. Two tools are the same yes, however I have children who did not do the assessment due to their age, but parents and teacher assessed them.

I have the assessment related to social and emotional learning of students. Teacher and parents assessed the students (from kindergarten do 12th grade) and the self-assessment was made by students with more than 8 years old. Mental Health was the same, except the self-assessment was only for those with more that 11 years-old.

Given your dataset, a multilevel modeling approach seems appropriate. It can handle the hierarchical structure of your data (e.g., assessments nested within students). You can include variables from different sources (teachers, parents, students) and assess their impact at different levels, and it can account for repeated measures over time, allowing you to assess changes within subjects across different waves.

You indeed have a situation in which you will need, or at least benefit from, multilevel modeling. In fact, classic repeated-measures approaches require complete data at all time-points, which is often impossible in studies like your example. In addition, your situation is slightly more complex than the ordinary hierarchical approach to growth modeling, in which measurements are nested in participants in a two-level model, with the possibility of other nesting levels (participants in schools, etc.).
In your situation, you have the source of the score changing as students age. It doesn't sound like this is true of every student, but at least some will have different types of scores (self-assessed v. parent / teacher assessed) throughout the study. This means that you're veering into a cross-classified random effects model. Fortunately, longitudinal researchers have shined a light on how to deal with this complexity. Two papers that I can recommend are Guo and colleagues, where the bias introduced by ignoring rater effects is discussed, and Cafri and colleagues who give examples of model specification issues and have two real-world design situations that are easy to follow.
However, your situation doesn't fit as nicely with those classic examples, so you will need to take care to specify your model appropriately in whatever statistical software you choose to use. It should be fairly straightforward to do so in R using lme4 or nlme. See this post for some guidance.
